# Floating/Embedded QDockWidget in a QWidget (KXmlGuiWindow's CentralWidget designed in QT Designer)

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, kde-plasma, kdevelop

I'm just trying to get into QT (and KDE) program, and have hit a snag trying to add a floatable, draggable `QDockWidget` to the .ui file (based as a `QWidget`) that is embedded into my KDE 4 program.

This is all from the basic template provided by KDevelop 4, so while I understand what's going on, I just don't know the best way to change it.

Here's the deal: main.cpp spawns a new `AEmpire` window, which starts the whole show off:

```
AEmpire::AEmpire()
       : KXmlGuiWindow(),
         m_view(new AEmpireView(this)),
         m_printer(0)
{
    // tell the KXmlGuiWindow that this is indeed the main widget
    setCentralWidget(m_view);

    setupActions();
    setupGUI();
}
```

When a new `AEmpireView(this)` is created (which inherits from `QWidget`) and is assigned to m_view, this constructor is called:

```
AEmpireView::AEmpireView(QWidget *)
{
    ui_aempireview_base.setupUi(this);
    settingsChanged();
    setAutoFillBackground(true);
}
```

So, when I am editing the ui to my program in QT Designer, I'm actually editing the `AEmpireView_base` ui file, which is a `QWidget`. It just represents the main view of the `KXmlGuiWindow` (derived from `QMainWindow`) and is loaded at runtime.

So, how do I add floatable, draggable `QDockWidget`s into my main application? Is designing them separately, and add them to the UI the best option? Or maybe removing the entire `AEmpireView` class, and making my ui file directly represent a `KXmlGuiWindow` object to be loaded by the `AEmpireClass`?

Or am I totally overlooking something obvious? Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 1):

I would design the QDockWidget contents as separate UI files. Then create them and stick them into the QDockWidgets in the AEmpire constructor.